# Pandas join on these two dataframes causes value error, but different errors for different versions, and why?

Tags: python, pandas

Possible duplicate [pandas - Merging on string columns not working (bug?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39582984/pandas-merging-on-string-columns-not-working-bug)

I am getting interesting messages when trying to merge the following two dataframes.  Does anyone know what's going on? Removing the E fixes the error.

```
newvi = pd.DataFrame({'a':['E1000305', 'E1000505', 'E1001071', 'E99836', 'E1003822']})
newsm = pd.DataFrame({'a':['E1000305', 'E1000305', 'E1000305', 'E1000305', 'E1000305']})

newvi.a
#0    E1000305
#1    E1000505
#2    E1001071
#3      E99836
#4    E1003822
#Name: a, dtype: object
newsm.a
#0    E1000305
#1    E1000305
#2    E1000305
#3    E1000305
#4    E1000305
#Name: a, dtype: object

newvi.join(newsm, on='a')

#my computer
#ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index([u'a'], dtype='object')

>>> pd.__version__
u'0.18.1'

#server

#ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

>>> pd.__version__
'0.24.2'
```

Comment: What do you want the joined data frame to look like?

Answer (score 0):

`newvi.join(newsm.set_index('a'), on='a')`

Setting the index to 'a' seems to resolve your error, does the result match your expectation?

Comment: It solves it yes. But still interested why it's happening

Comment: It seems to be related to the behaviour of `on` in join and how it uses index's. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html Refer to `on` documentation.

Comment: I think it’s a bug no